# finding value of theta using the equation of circle

Tags: javascript, math

Using the equation of circle I have

```
x = rCos(theta)
y = rSin(theta)
```

Now I want to calculate theta. I have

```
x = -87.91
r = 14.63
```

what will be the value of theta? using

```
Math.acos(x/r)
```

its giving me NaN...

Comment: *"The acos method returns a numeric value between 0 and pi radians for x between -1 and 1. If the value of number is outside this range, it returns NaN."* https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/acos

Comment: Yes, your numbers must be wrong. The point can be no more than `r` away from the origin so -87 is impossible for a circle of radius 14. Is your circle definitely centered at the origin?

Comment: how can find theta from the above equation?

Comment: You're correct, theta = arccos(x/r). It's just there's no theta that can generate that value of `x` given that value of `r`. (Unless you're talking complex numbers I suppose?)

Answer (score 3):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/acos)

> The acos method returns a numeric value between 0 and pi radians for
>   x between -1 and 1. If the value of number is outside this range, it
>   returns NaN.

You need to get it within the range.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `x = -87.91`, than `r >= 87.91`, so you have something wrong.

The best method in such situations is usually `theta = Math.atan2(y, x)` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Answer (score 1):

sine and cosine don't have true inverses unless you restrict their range. So the acos and asin methods are only defined over these restricted ranges (which become the domains of asin and acos).

Comment: @coure2011: as pointed out Rup you have another bug in your program.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that `theta` is a value in radians, and that sentiment has been echoed thoroughly.  If you don't want to convert values before you enter them, then you can use a conversion formula while calculating `x` and `y`.

```
x = rCos(theta * (3.14/180))
y = rSin(theta * (3.14/180))
```

Comment: I don't think degrees/radians is the problem here. He's trying to compute theta from x and r, and he's using a JavaScript function that returns radians.